# How to correctly change Embedded provision profile in .xcarchive?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I search a way to change embedded provision profile programmatically in .xcarchive.

In old version of **xcodebuild** commant i can use:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "projectname.xcarchive" -exportPath "path" -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile “Provisioning Profile Name”
```

This way allowed create ipa with another provision, instead of using a embedded provision profile.
But it already deprecated.

Can I change embedded provision profile using this command? :

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath <path/to/your.xcarchive> -exportOptionsPlist <path/to/exportOptions.plist> -exportPath <output-path>
```

Or can I only replace embedded provision file from .xcarchive package content and generate .ipa (if yes, should I sign archive again)?

I know, that I can resign generated .ipa file, but I need to change provision before generating .ipa file.